# How to send multiple binary files to the browser?

Tags: download

I have a file management app, users can view individual files from their browser (pdf, and images)
I want to implement a backup feature allowing users to download all their files 
Volumes for a backup would be a few hundreds files for a few hundreds Mo

Files will be stored in a key / value storage (Riak)

The app server will be RoR + Unicorn in the same network as the Riak server

What i'm planning to do:
. the app server asynchronously downloads all user files in a temp dir
. creates a zip with files on the app server
. when the zip is ready client can ask for a link to the zip

Do you have any better idea ?

I'm still in early development, i'm open to suggestion on the architecture (ex: replace Riak)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case somebody has the same question, i ended up doing what i had described